# Why can't I remove a group with icacls from a file after revoking read access?

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

Why can't I remove a group from a file if it is being denied read permission even though I have read permission from my account, am part of the Administrators group, and I'm running icacls from an elevated command prompt?

This will remove the "Users" group just fine:

```
copy a b
icacls b /inheritance:d
icacls b /remove:g "Users"
```

> Result: The file no longer has the "Users" group.

But if I remove read access then the group cannot be removed by icacls:

```
copy a b
icacls b /inheritance:d
icacls b /deny "Users":r
icacls b /remove:g "Users"
```

> Result: The file still has the "Users" group.

To work around this I have to grant a group "full" permission first and then use `/remove` to guarantee that the group will be removed. But this feels like a vulnerability as a particular group will, briefly, have full access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong switch.  You need to use `/remove:d`:

```
icacls b /remove:d "Users"
```

When a group has been denied permissions, there are no rights for the `/remove:g` switch to remove.

Alternately, to remove *any* permissions assigned to the group, whether they are grant or deny, use:

```
icacls b /remove "Users"
```

**Summary**

- `/remove:g` removes rights that are **(G)ranted**
- `/remove:d` removes rights that are **(D)enied**
- `/remove` removes all rights

---

More information about Icacls switches can be found on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I had to use `/remove BUILTIN\Users` on my server. Don't know why `BUILTIN\` was required on a remove, works just fine on grants.